# Magento 1.4 to 1.9 Customer, Sales and Invoice Export/Import

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento Version 1.4.*.* and i have to export our customers, sales and invoices to our new Magento Version 1.9.*.* .

I tried to use the magento export functionality but that doesnt work.

So i googled a little bit and found some Magento Extension for Export/Import but i am not sure if these Extensions are working.

Also i found some entries here at stackoverflow that there´s a possibility to import database tables but that also didnt work :-(.

Now I am uncertain how I can proceed? Can someone help me.